# Chrome App Identity Login Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, nwjs

I tried using chorome.identity to auth my app but it seems NWJS can not load login page that provided by chrome at chrome://chrome-signin/?access_point=6&reason=0.
I have my package.json just like this:

```
 "permissions": ["tabs", "identity", "storage", "https://www.googleapis.com/*",
        "https://*.googleusercontent.com/*",
        "https://ssl.gstatic.com/",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/",
        "https://accounts.google.com/",
        "chrome://chrome-signin/?access_point=6&reason=0"],

    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
        ]
    },
    "key": "MIIBIjANBxxxxxxx"
```

and this is my code:

```
 chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive': true}, function (token) {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                return;
            }

            console.log('Tokennya adalah', token);
        });
```

is there any wrong code I've written?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly your oauth2 `client_id` does not match the package id of your extension. When generating oauth2 token for chrome app, it will ask for your app's web store id after you upload the initial app with the manifest. Check if it is the same as that of your extension loaded to the chrome for development. If not, give the local extension instead of the web store id. And use that client_id in your manifest for development. Later on change it to the webstore url id to publish.
And there is no need for "chrome://chrome-signin/?access_point=6&reason=0" url under permissions.